# Design Pattern for Objects of the same type sharing various fields

Tags: java, list, object, design-patterns, share

The title may sound strange, but it's easier with the explanation:

Basically I have this class X. There is always a even number of those objects. For each two of those objects should exist 1 list that can be acessed from both of them.

For example if I create 4 X objects: A1, A2, B1, B2, I will need to have 2 lists, one that can only be acessed by A1 and A2 and another one only to be acessed by B1 and B2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not be looking for a class definition. You should be looking for a design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I will read about it :). @m0skit0 unfortunately my english is not very bright. What I mean is to always have 1 list shared by two objects. I will reformulate the question.

Comment: Are A1, A2, B1 and B2 all instances of X, or instances of A and B respectively? If it's the second case, you can use a static List for A and B.

Comment: @m0skit0 A1,A2,B1,B2 are all from the same type -> X

Comment: @m0skit0 - Only one Class. 4 Objects, 2 lists. He is sub-classifying types.

Comment: You can create one list for each two instances, than create each of the two using a giving the list as constructor argument.

Comment: @BobTheBuilder - But what will prevent B's from Accessing ListForA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you encapsulate the 2 objects and a list into another object? In this example, your objects are still instances of X, and the encapsulating class is Y:

```
/**
  * Encapsulates 2 X's and a List
  */
public class Y {

  private X x1;
  private X x2;
  private List list;

  public Y() {
    list = //..create list
    x1 = new X(list);
    x2 = new X(list);
  }
}
```

Have this class in the same package as X, and hide X's constructor to package level (default). If it's not the default (no arguments) constructor (as is the case here), write a private constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Let me improve the answer of Tim B. I also think that a factory pattern is what you need.
First, class `X` takes a reference to a list.

```
abstract class X<T> { 
  List<T> list;

  public X(List<T> l) { list = l; }
}
```

By contract, all classes extending X have to take a list and hand it over to `super(list)` in the constructor, for example

```
abstract class A<T> extends X<T> { 

  public A(List<T> l) { super(L); }
}
// others like B also declared similar
```

In the factory, we "count" the instances in a `Map<Class, List<?>>` and hand the associated list over to the implementation.

```
public class Factory {

    Map<Class<?>, List<?>> class2List = new HashMap<Class<?>, List<?>(); // you may need a synchronized version here

    <T> X<T> createInstance(Class<X<T>> class) {
        List<T> list;
        // Idea: If the HashMap contains the class, we already created one instance before.
        if (class2List.contains(class)) {
            // second instance. Remove to implicitly count from 0 again
            list = (List<T>) class2List.remove(class);
        } else {
            list = new ArrayList<T>();
            class2List.add(list);
        }
        // now create the instance depending on the class and give it the list.
        // For example
        X<T> result;
        if (class.equals(A.class)) {
            result = new A<T>(list);
        } else  {
            result = new B<T>(list);
        }
        return result

    }


}
```

Comment: Dam that's too much for my current knowledge. I think im getting it +- but theres something wrong, maybe I didnt explained myself correctly. A and B are not types, they are X objects, where we have A and B we could have Ants and Burps, it's just a name, not a type. Maybe I messed up with capital leter. My bad, but im really apreciated for your effort.

Comment: Thanks :) The general idea is to use the HashMap as sort of Bucket. Do I get an upvote? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a factory here. One call to the factory generates A and B, sets up the shared members, then returns them to you either in an Array or in some sort of results Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one list for each two instances, than create each of the two using a giving the list as constructor argument.

Each object will access its list only, so B1,B2 will use a different list than A1,A2.

You can create a `Map<String, List<>>` that holds name and list.

Each time you create an object, get its list from the map. If it doesn't in map, create a new list and put it there.

Comment: Well, that might work and makes perfect sense. The problem is that the order of creation might not be A1,A2,B1,B2 more like A1,B1,D1,C1...

Comment: And how do you decide which objects has the same list?

Comment: Well, that's the problem. Each object has a name, so objects with the same name will have the same list. I just can't figure out when or how to do it.

Comment: How about everytime that an object is created check on the List if there's already an object with the same name, get a reference to that object, create one list and point both objects to dat list? It's a bit ugly.

Comment: See my reply how you could do it :)